# Caliburn Micro WPF Grid with CSLA MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, grid, csla, caliburn

First Question :
Need help on binding WPF Grid with CSLA MVVM approach using Caliburn Micro. Any links or sample available ? Using WPF Grid with CSLA MVVM with Caliburn Micro

The Grid will bind to Model Collection View Source.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Nathan, thanks , I modified my post in to two separate questions . Kindly assist